# URLSCAN question

Tags: urlscan

I have uriscan installed on my Win2003 server and it is blocking an older ColdFusion script.  The log entry has the following--

2008-09-19 00:16:57 66.82.162.13 1416208729 GET /Admin/Uploads/Mountain/Wolf%2520Creek%2520gazeebo.jpg Rejected URL+is+double+escaped URL - -

How do I get uriscan to allow submissions like this without turning off the double-escaped url feature?

Answer (score 1):

To quote another post on the subject,

> some aspect of your process for
> submitting URIs is doing some bad
> encoding.
>
> http://www.usenet-forums.com/archive/index.php/t-39111.html

I recommend changing the name of the JPG to not have spaces in it as a good practice, then later try to figure out with a non-production page why you're not interpreting the %20 as an encoded space, but as a percent sign and two digits.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get uriscan to allow
>   submissions like this without turning
>   off the double-escaped url feature?

How do you get it to allow double-escaped URLs without turning off the double-escaped url feature?  I think there's something wrong with what you're trying to do.  My question is this: does your HTML source literally show image requests with "%2520" in them?  Is that the correct name for your file?  If so, you really have only two options: rename the file or turn off the feature disallowing double escapes.